# Setting modalPresentationStyle to custom causes wrong status bar color in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've a simple controller that shows another controller with a custom transition. I use a solid navigation bar:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

This is the second controller:
[image]

When I open a `MFMailComposeViewController` in the child controller, the status bar is white on white (this appens also with `UIActivityViewController`):
[image]

It turns out that this is related to setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCustom`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    // this line cause the bug
    //controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

    controller.transitioningDelegate = self;
}
```

The status bar color is correct if `controller.modalPresentationStyle` is left unchanged. Moreover, this property seems not to interfere with the custom transition.

I'm missing something here? Why `modalPresentationStyle` impacts on the status bar type in system controllers? Could this be a bug?

Full code is here https://github.com/mbigatti/StatusBarTest

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe you could try adding:

```
controller.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = YES
```

after setting the `modalPresentationStyle`. According to the [UIViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance):

> When you present a view controller by calling the presentViewController:animated:completion: method, status bar appearance control is transferred from the presenting to the presented view controller only if the presented controller’s modalPresentationStyle value is UIModalPresentationFullScreen. By setting this property to YES, you specify the presented view controller controls status bar appearance, even though presented non–fullscreen.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it indeed works. What is unclear to me is if controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom is required or not for custom transitions, because it seems that omitting that line produce the same result.

Comment: AFAIK if you want a custom transition you must use the UIModalPresentationCustom, but I haven't extensively tested that...

Comment: Using UIModalPresentationCustom specify how views of view controllers should be handled before and after transition and it is required only if the custom transition needs parent view controller's view to stay on the screen. When transitioning (with custom or default transition) to view controller which uses the whole screen (default behaviour), you don't need to specify this.